# How to solve "Is not an enclosing class error"when get data from Arduino

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arduino

I am trying to implement a thread to get data from my arduino device. Creating this thread in another function(manageMyConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket)) to use causes "Is not an enclosing class" error. When i make the thread "static" to solve this problem my Handler starts causing problem "non-static field 'Handler' cannot be referenced from a static context" Thank you for your help!

```
public static class MyBluetoothService {
        private static final String TAG = "MY_APP_DEBUG_TAG";
        private Handler handler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service

        // Defines several constants used when transmitting messages between the
        // service and the UI.
        private interface MessageConstants {
            public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
            public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
            public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;

            // ... (Add other message types here as needed.)
        }

        private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final InputStream mmInStream;
            private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
            private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

            public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
                mmSocket = socket;
                InputStream tmpIn = null;
                OutputStream tmpOut = null;

                // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
                // member streams are final.
                try {
                    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
                }
                try {
                    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
                }

                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                mmOutStream = tmpOut;
            }

            public void run() {
                mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

                // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // Read from the InputStream.
                        numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                        Message readMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                                MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                                mmBuffer);
                        readMsg.sendToTarget();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
            public void write(byte[] bytes) {
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(bytes);

                    // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
                    Message writtenMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
                    writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

                    // Send a failure message back to the activity.
                    Message writeErrorMsg =
                            handler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("toast",
                            "Couldn't send data to the other device");
                    writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
                    handler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
                }
            }

            // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //***MANAGE CONNECTED SOCKET ******MANAGE CONNECTED SOCKET ******MANAGE CONNECTED SOCKET ******MANAGE CONNECTED SOCKET ******MANAGE CONNECTED SOCKET ***
    private void manageMyConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {
        Log.println(Log.ERROR,"DEV","I AM IN THE MANAGEMYCONNECTEDSOCKET METHOD, SEEMS INTERESTING");
        MyBluetoothService.ConnectedThread dataThread= new MyBluetoothService.ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        dataThread.start();
    }
```